# Connect to ssh without Host Key Verification using j2ssh maverick

Tags: java, ssh, sftp, j2ssh

I have two servers with trusted connection. I want to transfer files through SFTP by connecting through ssh without Host Key Verification.

I am using Java 1.7 and Redhat Linux OS.

Previously i was using j2ssh-core0.2.9.jar in which i could connect to ssh like below :

```
SshConnectionProperties properties = new SshConnectionProperties();
SshClient ssh = new SshClient();            
properties.setHost(host);
properties.setPort(port);               
ssh.setSocketTimeout(readTimeOut);
ssh.connect(properties,new IgnoreHostKeyVerification());
```

In j2ssh maverick,

```
        SshConnector con = SshConnector.createInstance();
        con.getContext().setHostKeyVerification(
                new ConsoleKnownHostsKeyVerification());
        con.getContext().setPreferredPublicKey(
                Ssh2Context.PUBLIC_KEY_SSHDSS);
        SocketTransport t = new SocketTransport(hostname, port);
        t.setTcpNoDelay(true);
        SshClient ssh = con.connect(t, username);
        Ssh2Client ssh2 = (Ssh2Client) ssh;
```

Please suggest how to achieve this in j2ssh maverick.

Comment: What's wrong with the j2ssh code that you posted? Please describe your specific problem.

Comment: @Kenster There are no updates after 2009 for j2ssh-core0.2.9. So opted to go for j2ssh maverick. There are some bugs also in j2ssh-core and no support also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To connect without host key verification you just need to remove the following code fro the J2SSH Maverick snippet

```
con.getContext().setHostKeyVerification(
                new ConsoleKnownHostsKeyVerification());
```

However you are removing an important part of the protocol that authenticates the server. Leaving you fully open to a man-in-the-middle attack.